# Does anyone know the name of this part?

Tags: vw, manual-transmission, part-identification, shifting, jetta

My Vw Jetta 2005 (manual transmission) is having a hard time switching gears. Found out this was the problem. Does anyone know the name of this?

[image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrgMR.jpg)

Comment: some information about where you found it will help a lot,on the gearbox-gear stick location please.

Comment: https://youtu.be/kPII13ZUBZE

Answer (score 1):

That's part of the gear linkage, either the selector cable end or the shifter cable end, it's impossible to tell which from the picture.